# User cannot access folder in network mapped drive despite having rights

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Good afternoon,

I have an issue where one of my users cannot access to a specific folder in a mapped drive. It has access to the drive but not the folder. When I examine the security dialog (right click on the folder, properties) the user is allowed to modify, read, list the folder.

I've been trying to look in the event viewer in case there is an error when trying to access the folder, but without success.

Can someone suggest way to troubleshoot this issue, I'm still learning so any advice will be great.

Comment: You should check both SHARE and NTFS permissions. https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/05/03/differences-between-share-and-ntfs-permissions/

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the very late answer. So apparently the issue was that on CREATOR OWNER the permission was deny. I don't really understand the link between this.